# "Tell Don't Ask," shouldn't all methods be void?

Tags: java, oop

I've been reading a lot about TDA and the pros and cons of getter and setter methods, and though I don't necessarily agree with everything I've read, assuming you should always tell rather than ask, and that you should avoid accessor methods whenever possible, wouldn't that imply that all methods should return void to comply with these guidelines/ideals?

I understand that realistically not all methods should return void, but I'd just like to fully understand this whole way of looking at OOP. I can't seem to find an explanation anywhere else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Tell, Don't Ask", all by itself, is a silly over-generalized rule, not an ideal.

The *ideal* is that an object has *one* job, it does the *whole* job, and its class is the place you put code that does that job.

But, there is this problem in the minds of many developers that makes them compromise this ideal...

Let's say you're working in a big code base that you share with a lot of others, and you get a special requirement:  In your specific use case, you need object X to do its job differently.  In some ways, the *safest* way to do this is to keep the code for your special case separate.  That usually means that you have to detect your special case, query the state of X so you can decide what you want it to do in your special case, and then tell X to do it.

Unfortunately, what usually happens when you do this, is that you make your special case code do part of X's job.  It's looking at internal information about X that it has no business looking at, and using it to make decisions that it has no business making.  Now there is no one place to look for the code that does X's job, and even though *your* little change is safe, it's much harder for everyone to figure out how X's job gets done.

So, don't do this.  The "Don't Ask" part of "Tell, Don't Ask" means stop asking for this internal information you have no business seeing and making decisions that are really X's job.

The alternative is to tell.  Add a method or something to X that lets you say "I need you to work a bit differently now".  Try really hard *not* to make it all about your special little requirement, though.  Then, when your special case comes up, you just tell X what it needs to know about it, and leave the decisions that involve X's internal state to X.